# including pathnames

Tags: 12.04

I am very new to Linux. I have got installed Ubuntu 12.04 a day before. I could install a number of needed things like python, numpy, scipy, matplotlib, pygtk etc. However when I tried to get installed Atomic Simulation Environment on my system using command line prompt  I received a message like this

```
Resolving download.openuse.org(download.openuse.org)...failed:Name or service not known
```

So I quit that attempt and obtained the package as a tarball; issued following commands

```
$ cd $HOME
$ tar zxf python-ase-3.8.0.3420.tar.gz
$ ln -s python-ase-3.8.0.3420 ase
```

what they further ask to do is

"It is sufficient to put the directory `$HOME`/ase in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, and the directory `$HOME/ase/tools` in your `PATH` environment variable. Do this permanently in your `~/.bashrc` file:"

What does this mean and how to get it done

they have shown the commands for this as

```
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/ase:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=$HOME/ase/tools:$PATH
```

why these commands do not start with $

My terminal always opens with $ at the beginning. can I issue these commands there?

Comment: Your download site should be download.opensuse.org, not download.openuse.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you really need is to install [python-ase](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/python-ase).

This package is available for Ubuntu since 12.10 (not 12.04), but the versions available in the Ubuntu archives are a bit old.

So if you need to install the upstream version, open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-gtk2 python-central
cd $HOME/Downloads/
wget https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/python-ase-3.9.0.3584.tar.gz
tar -zxvf python-ase-3.9.0.3584.tar.gz
cd python-ase-3.9.0.3584/
sudo ./setup.py install
```

Now you can run a python interpreter to check that **ASE** is properly installed:

```
sylvain@sylvain-ThinkPad-T430s:~/Downloads/python-ase-3.9.0.3584$ python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ase import Atoms
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the timely help ! By this time I have already got my PC ready with python-ase I however have tumbled upon another glitch. I am now unable to perform istallation of DACAPO code on the system so as to run it alongwith ase-python. I have downloaded the DACAPO tarball containing Pseudopotentials and Planewave utilities. I have stored the file in my HOME directory but do not know how to get it running.